# RegEx How do I match square bracket tags with a pipe in the middle?

Tags: php, regex

```
preg_match_all("[[Train]]<p />[[Plane]]<p />[[Crane Sane]]<p />[[Slain (derp)|Slained]]",$regex,$out);
```

I want to just extract: -

[[Slain (derp)|Slained]]

This is what I have so far: -

```
$regex = "/\[\[.+?\\|.+?\]\]/";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$regex = "/(\[\[[^\\]]+?\\|[^\\]]+?\]\])/";
preg_match($regex,"[[Train]]<p />[[Plane]]<p />[[Crane Sane]]<p />[[Slain (derp)|Slained]]",$out);
print_r($out[1]);
```

http://www.ideone.com/8YisP

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will work and only capture what you are looking for:

```
<?php
    $test_string = "[[Train]]<p />[[Plane]]<p />[[Crane Sane]]<p />[[Slain (derp)|Slained]]";
    $regex = "/\[\[[^[]+\|[^\]]+\]\]/";
    preg_match_all($regex,$test_string,$out);

    print_r($out);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex will start at the `[[` in `[[Train` and then slurp all the characters up to the next pipe, which just happens to be in another `[[`…`]]` construct altogether. As a first approximation, you should exclude all closing brackets before you see the pipe.

```
"\[\[[^]]+\\|[^[]+\]\]"
```